# Only test databases showing from MySQL prompt

Tags: mysql

This is my first time using MySQL. I have Windows and XAMPP installed .

I have created a database called "Students" through my Java program that shows up as a folder in the C:\xampp\mysql\data directory, and in localhost/phpmyadmin/. I can query tables in the database from Java.

In the Xampp folder, mysql.exe is found in C:\xampp\mysql\bin. This is what displays from the prompt there:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

Files with these names exist in C:\xampp\mysql\mysql-test.

I was expecting to see my database here. I gather perhaps I can tell it to look in a different place by editing the my.cnf file. But there is one in C:\xampp\mysql\mysql-test\suite\rpl and one in C:\xampp\mysql\mysql-test\suite\federated. Neither contains "datadir". Am I on the right path? What do I do?

Comment: Did you create the `Students` DB using the same user account?  `SHOW DATABASES` will only show databases you have privileges to.

Comment: In the Java program, I supply user:root and the password. I haven't thought about this at all when using the prompt, I just type "mysql" from cmd and then "show databases". Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes it was! Showing fine now. If you want to post the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you create the Students DB using the same user account? SHOW DATABASES will only show databases you have privileges to.

Comment: This was the problem. I needed to supply the same user and password that I created the database with when I launched the MySQL command line (in my case "mysql -u root -p").